# Word or phrase to describe music that 'transports' you somewhere

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Looking for a **word or phrase for a feeling of being 'transported' somewhere**, **particularly when listening to music**, but that doesn't necessarily describe the emotions of happiness or sadness.

> I've considered *'melancholic'*, but it is related to sadness.
>
> I've considered *'uplifting', 'enraptured', and 'euphoric'* but those are related to joy or happiness.
>
> The closest I've come is to 'transcendent'. But that seems to describe some kind of transportation across planes of existences, not some other physical location.

Examples:

> - "Wow, when I listen to ~insert electronic song~, it feels like I'm on Mars"

or

> - "That song makes me feel as if I'm driving down a forest road while it's snowing"

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not *[transportive](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transportive)*? You could say, “This music has a transportive quality about it” or something along those lines.

This works well because [one of the definitions of *transport*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transports) is “to carry away with strong and often intensely pleasant emotion.” (See definition 2.)

Comment: Of course! I don't have enough rep to upvote you on this stack but thanks!

Comment: @OhNoNotALinkerError Don’t mention it! Perhaps when you do get enough reputation you’ll upvote me. ;-)

Comment: Someone downvoted, they are wrong. This is a great answer. Though a little obscure, that's often a character you want in a word for this situation.